# How can I reference external dependencies (gems) in hologram source?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

We're using hologram to create our styleguide. 
We moved some of our documented styles into an external gem in order to share them with a different project. Now we're having a hard time getting the style guide to see the scss files in the gem. 
In our hologram yml config our source looks like this. How can we get it to actually reference the gem and not the hard coded path?

```
source:
  - ./app/assets
  - ./public/styleguideforlovelydesigners/
  # TODO: this should use the actual GEM_PATH
  - ../our_gem/app/assets/stylesheets/shared_components
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could package the gem in your `vendor` directory; and use that path.  An alternative would be to plug the gem's full path into the yaml file:

```
source:
  - ./app/assets
  - ./public/styleguideforlovelydesigners/
  # TODO: this should use the actual GEM_PATH
  - <%= Gem.loaded_specs['our_gem'].full_gem_path %>/app/assets/stylesheets/shared_components
```